# NSDateFormatter returning NULL on 3rd of three uses

Tags: xcode, cocoa, null, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Ok, this one has me baffled, and I'm hoping some fresh perspective can lead me to the right conclusion here...  I am getting a NULL returned form the NSDateFormatter on the third item I attempt to use it for and I can't seem to figure out why.  Here's my code:

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDate *tempDate;

[format setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"]; 
tempDate = [format dateFromString:[activePerformance performanceDate]];
[outletPerformanceDate setDateValue:tempDate];

// display performance time and set length

[format setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];  
tempDate = [format dateFromString:[activePerformance performanceTime]];             
[outletPerformanceTime setDateValue:tempDate];
```

Both of these work correctly and as intended.  And then, there's this one:

```
[format setDateFormat:@"MMM dd yyyy"];
tempDate = [format dateFromString:[activeFan birthday]];
[outletFansBirthday setDateValue:tempDate];
```

It returns NULL to tempDate every time.  Running NSLogs, we can see that the [activeFan birthday] is set to "May 2, 1980" or whatever date was placed into the variable.  Since this didn't work, I changed it to this for testing:

```
[format setDateFormat:@"MMM dd yyyy"];
tempDate = [format dateFromString:@"Jan 22, 1976"];  // TESTING
```

It still returns NULL every time.

I thought perhaps something was happening between these lines of code (they are not directly adjacent, but are in the same method) but there's nothing that has anything to do with NSDate, NSDateFormatter, or any of these object variables.  Just several outlets to NSTextFields.

I am completely at a loss.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format string has to match the string you supply in your dateFromString: method.  In the last version, you have no comma in your format string, but you do in your test string (and presumably in [activeFan birthday].

Comment: ::::BANGS HEAD AGAINST WALL:::  Two hours because of a missing comma... I knew I needed a fresh perspective... Ugh.  Thanks!